# Data Structures

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am coding a program which is basically going to compute the number of inversions in the array. The requirement is to use a divide-and-conquer algorithm.
I have used merge sort but afterwards I am stuck. I need to create another method called count in order to count the inversions using recursion. Here I need your help... 
Thank you in advance

```
    import java.util.*;

public class inversions
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer[] a = {2, 6, 3, 5, 1};
        mergeSort(a);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }

    public static void mergeSort(Comparable [ ] a)
    {
        Comparable[] tmp = new Comparable[a.length];
        mergeSort(a, tmp,  0,  a.length - 1);
    }


    private static void mergeSort(Comparable [ ] a, Comparable [ ] tmp, int left, int right)
    {
        if( left < right )
        {
            int center = (left + right) / 2;
            mergeSort(a, tmp, left, center);
            mergeSort(a, tmp, center + 1, right);
            merge(a, tmp, left, center + 1, right);
        }
    }


    private static void merge(Comparable[ ] a, Comparable[ ] tmp, int left, int right, int rightEnd )
    {
        int leftEnd = right - 1;
        int k = left;
        int num = rightEnd - left + 1;

        while(left <= leftEnd && right <= rightEnd)
            if(a[left].compareTo(a[right]) <= 0)
                tmp[k++] = a[left++];
            else
                tmp[k++] = a[right++];

        while(left <= leftEnd)    // Copy rest of first half
            tmp[k++] = a[left++];

        while(right <= rightEnd)  // Copy rest of right half
            tmp[k++] = a[right++];

        // Copy tmp back
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++, rightEnd--)
            a[rightEnd] = tmp[rightEnd];
    }
    public int count(int[] A, int n){}

}
```

Comment: You should count the inversions while performing merge sorting. Every time, when you put element from the second group (`index >= right`), you increase the counter by 1.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Correction: not by 1, but by the number of elements left in the first group?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg what is the index?

Comment: This might help http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/

Answer (score 0):

Added some changes in Your Code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class inversions
{
    public static int countInversions = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer[] a = {2, 6, 3, 5, 1};
        mergeSort(a);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        System.out.println(countInversions);
    }

    public static void mergeSort(Comparable [ ] a)
    {
        Comparable[] tmp = new Comparable[a.length];
        mergeSort(a, tmp,  0,  a.length - 1);
    }


    private static void mergeSort(Comparable [ ] a, Comparable [ ] tmp, int left, int right)
    {
        if( left < right )
        {
            int center = (left + right) / 2;
            mergeSort(a, tmp, left, center);
            mergeSort(a, tmp, center + 1, right);
            merge(a, tmp, left, center + 1, right);
        }
    }


    private static void merge(Comparable[ ] a, Comparable[ ] tmp, int left, int right, int rightEnd )
    {
        int leftEnd = right - 1;
        int k = left;
        int num = rightEnd - left + 1;

        while(left <= leftEnd && right <= rightEnd)
            if(a[left].compareTo(a[right]) <= 0)
                tmp[k++] = a[left++];
            else {
                countInversions+=((leftEnd-left)+1); // Counts the inversions
                tmp[k++] = a[right++];
            }

        while(left <= leftEnd)    // Copy rest of first half
            tmp[k++] = a[left++];

        while(right <= rightEnd)  // Copy rest of right half
            tmp[k++] = a[right++];

        // Copy tmp back
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++, rightEnd--)
            a[rightEnd] = tmp[rightEnd];
    }
}
```

In the above code, we are counting the inversions when two arrays are merging. For example 1st sub-array contains [1, 6] and 2nd sub-array has [2, 3]. So when these are merged together inversion count will be 2 i.e. [6>2] & [6>3]. When the condition comes that a[left] > a[right] it will count the number of elements remaining on the right sub-array because will be less than the a[left] and will add them to countInversions.

Comment: Also if you want to implement a method to count inversions you can just call the mergesort() from your method.